# Google Chrome Shortcut that Opens Many Web Pages in Many Tabs

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, web, shortcut

I'm trying to find a way to make a shortcut for Google Chrome that will open multiple specific webpages in multiple tabs. Right now I am using a Google Chrome desktop shortcut and command line switches to accomplish this, but it is falling short. I have this line of code in the target textbox (right click shortcut > properties > target textbox) right now:

```
C:\Users\ComputerName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --new-window --incognito "http://URL1" "http://URL2"
```

---

This does almost exactly what I want. Google Chrome opens in a new incognito window with the URLs in separate tabs. Except, there is one big problem. The target textbox only allows for a very limited amount of characters. I need to open multiple URLs in multiple tabs, most likely 8 or more. All my URLs will not fit in the target textbox.

On top of that it appears the `--disable-images` switch does not work for Windows 7. I would like to disable images along with Java and Flash to improve performance when opening so many tabs.

---

**So, how can I get a shortcut that opens Google Chrome in a new incognito Window with multiple tabs going to multiple different websites (URLs)?**

Preferably with images disabled and possibly with Java and Flash disabled. (Keep in mind this shortcut could be a .bat file or something of the like.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Notepad and type:

```
@echo off
start www.thewindowsclub.com
start www.bing.com
start www.google.com
```

In the above case, all the three sites will open in your default browser.

If you want the different links to open in different browsers, you can specify the browser as follows:

```
@echo off
start iexplore http://www.iot.qa/
start chrome http://www.iot.qa/
start firefox http://www.iot.qa/
```

Here the three links will open separately in the browsers specified.

After everything above is done, we now need to save the Notepad file. So click `File > Save As`. Then users will need to enter a file name; it can be anything, as long as it contains .bat at the end. For this to happen, click the drop-down menu that says “Text Document” and click “All Files.” Rename the file and add the `.bat` and hit save.

Comment: Might there be a way to do this on a Mac? I would be thankful for a suggestion

Answer (score 4):

Write a batch file and make it say:

@echo off

start chrome -incognito "URL1"
start chrome -incognito "URL2"

The exact steps are shown in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6toSwPewo8